# facebook meta tags issue

Tags: facebook, wordpress, meta-tags

am having a wordpress site 
http://wp1.mummypages.ie/show-pictures/

i want to edit the description tag to be shared on facebook when i click like, so when i edit the header file which calls get_facebook_meta function to meta type="description content="facebook_tag" ,facebook still recieves the old description content..

I have to edit it at any cost and i don't understand the reason from where it's fetching the description and how should i edit it??

can anyone help me?? will hugely appreciate it..

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Meta_Tags_in_WordPress

> To add meta tags to your site, simply add them to the header.php template file in your WordPress Theme

Comment: well solution found :)
facebook creates cache of the meta plugins once used and declared, so if you want to update the meta tags ,lint them first with the new tags and facebook automatically update them.

Comment: Also Facebook will relint them automatically after 24 hours.